# Automatic Exclusive Checkout for a Single File in TFS 2010

Tags: entity-framework, tfs

I am having problems with my fellow developers checking out edmx (Entity Framework) files, in that changes made by different developers can't be auto merged.

Is there a way to configure an automatic exclusive checkout from TFS, so that only one person can be working on that file at a time?

I'm looking for a solution that applies only to one file in the entire solution (rather than everything).

Comment: Worth noting that even in TFS 2010 the built-in merge tool is, um, not so great. We use a third-party merge which *significantly* more frequently can automatically merge.

Comment: @AakashM, I use the tool from StarTeam, which isn't available separately. However, many people report good results with Araxis Merge or Beyond Compare, which are available as standalone apps.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know about per-*file*, but anyway it sounds like you want per-*file type*, which *is* supported.

From VS while connected to TFS, go `Team | Team Project Collection Settings | Source Control File Types...`, then add a new file type for edmx files with the 'Enable file merging and multiple check out' checkbox **unchecked**.

Comment: Indeed, it cannot be done per-file, it must be done per file extension.

Comment: Also, in case you don't find the option, someone who may be reading this, this needs a permission to enable this feature.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253112.aspx